# OMNET++/MIXIM : HOW CAN I CORRECT THE FOLLOWING COMPILER'S ERROR

Tags: simulation, omnet++, mixim

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

**make: *** Config file '' does not exist -- add the OMNeT++ bin directory to the path so that opp_configfilepath can be found, or set the OMNETPP_CONFIGFILE variable to point to Makefile.inc.  Stop. Makefile    /IWF    line 55 C/C++ Problem**

Comment: First of all: **YOU SHOULDN'T BE SHOUTING AT US!** writing in ALL CAPS is considered SHOUTING and it's rude - don't do it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with OMNET++ 4.3.1, it turns out that i extracted the omnet source files to C:\Omnet rather than the default expected location c:/omnetpp-4.3.1 by the make script. So when you try to build the mixim, the build stops by giving two errors one of them being

```
make: *** Config file 'c:/omnetpp-4.3.1/Makefile.inc' does not exist --
```

To solve this issue, navigate to mixim(or whatever folder)>out>gcc-debug>.last-copts or you can search your workspace for something like omnetpp-**4.3.1**, remember the version, to locate the file. Then just change -Ic:/omnetpp-4.*.*/include to exact directory path where you have extracted omnet++.